# FileZilla: Moving file into directory where file already exists fails with "failure"

Tags: rename, filezilla

I need to drag-n-drop `file_1` from `dir_1` into `dir_2` where there also exists a `file_1`. I want it to be overwritten.

I can do this with drag-n-drop from my local machine, but I can no longer drag-n-drop from another FileZilla directory. I get an error:

```
mv /home/path/file_1.png /home/path2/file_1.png: failure
```

I was able to do this until a couple of days ago. Then it would end by saying "successfully renamed." I haven't changed any settings. I'm using version 3.12.0.2. I don't think that I updated recently, but perhaps I did.

The command above works from shell, logged in with the same user. I can also drag a file into a folder where there isn't already a file with the same name.

This is pretty important because I like to upload all my files to a temp directory before moving them to the final production directory. This is to avoid upload connection issues affecting what's in the production dir.

PS: Am I the only one with this issue? Have any of you tried in version 3.12.0.2 and it worked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I assume you are using an SFTP protocol (as you have an SSH access and from the "failure" message, see below).*

With the SFTP protocol, FileZilla simply sends `SSH_FXP_RENAME` request to the SFTP server. FileZilla does not check if the target file already exists, let alone trying to delete it before renaming a source file.

According to an [SFTP specification](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-secsh-filexfer-02#section-6.5):

> It is an error if there already exists a file with the name specified by newpath.

And indeed the most widespread SFTP server implementation, the OpenSSH, will fail the `SSH_FXP_RENAME` request if the target file already exists. And it indeed fails with a rather cryptic "failure" error message, just as [OpenSSH SFTP server does in many cases](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/sftp_codes#code_4).

---

So I believe it could never have worked for you. Unless you were using a different SFTP server before, which violates the specification.

And it indeed turned out that you were using FTP before, not SFTP.